If a standard button is overriden with a flow, is it possible to get the record Id
I have a scenario where I am trying to get the recordID from an object when I create a new record. However, my new record is overriden with a custom aura component. The custom aura components calls various flows but I need the recordId to check what flow I want to run. The thing is when I run the component, it immediately opens in a new tab and I dont have any recordid coming in. Is this possible to do in salesforce?
<aura:component implements="force:hasRecordId,lightning:actionOverride,lightning:isUrlAddressable" access="global">
    <aura:handler name="init" value="{!this}" action="{!c.init}" />
    <lightning:card>
        <lightning:flow aura:id="flowData"  />
    </lightning:card>
</aura:component>

({
  init: function(component) {
    let flow = component.find("flowData");
    let recordId = component.get("v.recordId");
    var inputVariables = [{ name : "recordId", type : "String", value: recordId }];
    
    console.log(recordId)
    if (recordId) {
      let flowName;
      // Handle Account or Contact record types
      if (recordId.startsWith('001')) {
        flowName = "Payment_Processing_Flow_for_Accounts";
      } else if (recordId.startsWith('003')) {
        flowName = "Payment_Processing_Flow_for_Contacts";
      } else {
        flowName = "Payment_Processing_for_slim_cd_payment_related_list";
      }
      
      flow.startFlow(flowName, inputVariables);
    } else {
      let flowName = "Payment_Processing_Flow_on_Slimcd";
      flow.startFlow(flowName);
    }
  }
})


I see several problems, but I'm not sure how to address them in an answer. First, you defined the attribute recordId, but force:hasRecordId already defines it. This may be a problem. Second, you use v.sObjectType, but you didn't use force:hasSObjectName. Beyond that, there may be other problems with how the component is configured. I'd start with the two problems I mentioned to see if that gets things moving.

@sfdcfox, I have edited the code now. All I am trying to do is get the recordid to the aura component so I can pass it to the flow when I override a standard new button. At the moment, the recordid is always null. I was wondering if I am doing it the right way or theres a workaround
